# Phonegap: Getting contact name, but not a number

Tags: javascript, cordova, addressbook

I get the contact name, but not the numbers.
Where am I wrong?

Here's the code.

```
function loadPhoneContacts() {
    alert("Entering contacts");
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter="";
    options.multiple = true;
    var fields = ["displayName", "name", "nickname"];
    navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccessOfLoadContacts, onErrorOfLoadContacts, options);
}

function onSuccessOfLoadContacts(contacts) {

    alert("Got '" + contacts.length + "' contacts.");

    for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {

        var contactname =  contacts[i].name.formatted;
        alert(ContactName + " has " + contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length + " numbers");
        alert(contacts[i].phoneNumbers[1].value);

            for (var j=0; j<contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length; j++) {
                contactnumber = contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value;
                alert("Got number:" + contactnumber);
            }



    }
}

function onErrorOfLoadContacts(contactError) {
    alert('onError!');
}
```

The alert in the second for-loop doesn't get displayed.

I am a PG Noob.

Here's the updated (not working) code :

```
function loadPhoneContacts() {
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter="";
    options.multiple = true;
    var fields = ["displayName", "name", "nickname", "phoneNumbers"];
    navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccessOfLoadContacts, onErrorOfLoadContacts, options);
}

// onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current contacts
//
function onSuccessOfLoadContacts(contacts) {


    for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {

        alert(contacts[i].name.formatted);

            for (var j=0; j<contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length; j++) {
                alert(contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value);
            }

    }
}

// onError: Failed to get the contacts
//
function onErrorOfLoadContacts(contactError) {
    alert('onError!');
}
```

Added phoneNumbers in var field, removed variables and alerting them instead.

Comment: You should declare `contactnumber` with `var`.  That may be causing an error.

Comment: Is there definitely phoneNumbers for the contact?

Comment: Also 'ContactName' should be 'contactname' on the alert line

Comment: Pointy.. Declared, but not working yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not telling PhoneGap to load the PhoneNumbers, you need to add this to the required fields array:

```
var fields = ["displayName", "name", "nickname", "phoneNumbers"];
```

Comment: Added 'phoneNumbers' and corrected 'contactname'. Still no luck.

Comment: @SuperFunMan I just ran your updated code through Ripple and it works for me.

Comment: I am not aware of Ripple. What's that? I ran it on ios simulator and iPad. It still doesn't work. :(

Comment: Apologies, I should have given more detail. Ripple is a browser based testing environment for mobile/phonegap apps. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc

Comment: Thanks. The code also worked. I had to just delete the application from iPad and run it again. It doesn't work on simulator which is funny.